# How to disable efi on ASUS zenbook

Tags: bios, efi

I have just purchased an ASUS UX31A-DH51 Zenbook with Windows 8 preinstalled and I want to remove it and install Windows 7. However I can't load Windows 7, it hangs at the beginning of the install process. I figure I need to disable UEFI but I can't find an option to do that in the BIOS. Anyone have any ideas how I would go about installing Windows 7 or how to disable UEFI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an article I found at Seven Forums which might be helpful.

[How to Install Windows 7 Using the "Unified Extensible Firmware Interface" (UEFI)](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/186875-uefi-unified-extensible-firmware-interface-install-windows-7-a.html)

Interesting Warning about disabling UEFI:

> 1. Disabling UEFI will make the system unbootable as there is no MBR on the disks.
> 2. You CANNOT make a sector-by-sector copy of GPT disks. The Disk and Partition GUIDs will no longer be unique. This must never happen. You
>      can make a sector-by-sector copy of the contents of ESP or basic data
>      partitions.

Also found this on MSDN - [Installing Windows on UEFI Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463140.aspx)